# numpy append to an indexed array (after np.where)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I want to append values to a selection of array without having to go through a for loop.

i.e. if I want to add 0 values to certain locations of an array:

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])    
condition=np.where(a>2)    
a[condition]=np.append(a[condition],np.array([0]*len(condition[0])))

-> ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (12,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (6,)
```

Edit for clarification:

I need to add values (and dimension if needed) to selected array location. The loop looks like that:

```
for t in range(len(ind)):
    c = cols[t]
    r = rows[t]
    if data1[r, c] > 2:
        data2[r,c]=np.append(data2[r,c],t)
```

Is there any way to remove this loop (~100 000 iterations)? Thank

Comment: What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the pieces:

```
In [92]: a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]])    
    ...: condition=np.where(a>2)  
    ...: 
In [93]: a
Out[93]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
In [94]: condition
Out[94]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32))
In [95]: a[condition]
Out[95]: array([3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5])
In [96]: np.append(a[condition],np.array([0]*len(condition[0])))
Out[96]: array([3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

You are trying to put 12 values into 6 slots.  No can do!

What are you expecting?  I don't think I should even speculate.  Go ahead show us the loop.